Parallel logging without mixing up the log
I am trying to make my application faster by offloading some work onto seperate cores where possible. However I am now running into the problem that the logging I set up is being jubled up.
I found some intresting workarounds, but they are not really feasable without a massive rewrite. Im talking about a buffer that get written to, and then at the end it flushes it to the logger in one go.
What I am after is a way of grouping the output when a task is done.
Effectively.
Task 1 starts and logs it.
Task 2 starts and logs it.
Task 2 stops and logs it.
Task 1 starts and logs it.
But when you look back at the logs, Task 1 is grouped, and task 2 is grouped, or at least has some identifier.
I saw that loggers can us Logger.BeginScoped, but it does not seem to work in my case:
Parallel.foreach(files, => file
{
     using (_logger.BeginScope("{filename}", file.Name)) 
     {
         my code here
     }
}

Any suggestions would be appreciated!!!

You would need to add some more code, that reproduces the issue, perfectly better explain what is wrong with the output and provide the output, and provide also correct output example. And to be clear, multi threading or asynchronous processing does not span across multiple cores unless necessary :)

If you log to a database (and maybe use a "grouping key" to identify your groups) you could easily filter and/or group related entries regardless of their time of entry without holding entries back in a buffer.

What you ask is something that should be avoided at all costs. The only way to group log entries together is to delay writing until the "scope" is complete, taking up memory space and risking getting lost in case of problems. Log libraries store some action identifier instead, storing it as a separate field. The log readers use that field to group entries. If eg you use Serilog to write to a database, that extra ID will be a separate column.

The logging is IO bound, you can organize consumer/producer queue instead of calling logger methods directly and depending on log format multiple requests can be combined (bulk-written). I did something similar in past and at cost of higher memory consumption it worked pretty well to write thousands of log entries at once every 2 seconds or so.
